# Why isn't JavaScript resizing this image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, animation, image-resizing

I am trying to do a simple animation example in JavaScript. However, I have an image and I have tried everything that I have found on the internet and seen on previous posts and all that but I can't figure out why this image won't resize. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
        var x = 50;  
        var y = 20;  

        var xDirection = 1; 
        var yDirection = 1; 
        var image = new Image(); 
            image.src = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iS6eK4lSfi4/UJJRqbKA-VI/AAAAAAAABLA/HLxLJpCpau4/s320/Smiley-Face-2.jpg"; 
            image.style.width = "50px";  
            image.style.height = "50px"; 
        var canvas = null; 
        var context = null; 

        window.onload = init; 

        function init() {

            canvas = document.getElementById("gameSurface");
            context =canvas.getContext("2d"); 
            setInterval(draw, 1000/30); 
        } 


        function draw() {

            context.clearRect(0,0,500,500); 
            context.drawImage(image, x, y); 
            x += xDirection; 
            y += yDirection; 

            if ((x + 50) >= 500) {

                x = 450; 
                xDirection = -1; 

            }else if (x <= 0) {

                x = 0; 
                xDirection = 1; 
            } 

            if ((y + 50) >= 500) {

                y = 450; 
                yDirection = -1; 

            }else if (y <= 0) {

                y = 0; 
                yDirection = 1; 
            }
        }
```

As you can see all I want is a smiley face bouncing around the screen. I seem to always have issues with JS... and I do not know anything about JQuery, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resizing the img element by setting its style, but the canvas `.drawImage()` method doesn't use the element style. However `.drawImage()` *does* let you specify the size if you provide additional arguments:

```
context.drawImage(image, x, y, 50, 50);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vz28W/

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Scaling) for more details.